# You must subclass the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity and create an IntentFilter for it which matches your callbackUrl

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, google-oauth

I am building a Xamarin Forms application with Google Authentication via OAuth2. There are quite a few examples of integrating Google Authentication into Xamarin forms but most of these posts appear outdated.

The most recent instruction from Microsoft is to use Xamarin Essentials based on this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android) post. Microsoft's advice is to leverage a web backend to proxy the request to the third-party identity provider. In this case, I will be using an ASP.NET Core backend.

Within the Google cloud console, I have configured the **redirect url** of the OAuth **web application** to point to my deployed service instance in the cloud.  This url is:

```
https://my-google-app.appspot.com/signin-google
```

Assuming my ASP.NET Core app is exposed at base url **https://my-google-app.appspot.com.**

In *MobileAuthController*, that provides the authentication URL for the application, copied from this [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/develop/Samples/Sample.Server.WebAuthenticator) repo, the callback scheme is supposed to be the URL registered in my app for deep linking as per my understanding of the flow so far:

```
someappname://abc
```

assuming the package name of my Android application is com.my-app-package-name. This all appears or sounds reasonable.

Somewhere in the mobile application, I am initiating the authentication request using the Xamarin Essentials package as follows:

```
var result = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
            new Uri("https://my-google-app.appspot.com/mobileauth/Google"),
            new Uri("someappname://abc"));
```

In my Android project, I have an intent filter defined as follows:

```
[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new []{Android.Content.Intent.ActionView},
        Categories = new[] {Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable},
        DataPath ="abc",
        DataSchemes = new[]
            {
                "someappname"  /* package id */
            })
    ]

    public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {
    }
}
```

So far, so good :). However, when I run the application, I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'You must subclass the
> WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity and create an IntentFilter for it
> which matches your callbackUrl.

I have not been able to make sense of that error as Google will to redirect to my deployed ASP.NET instance which would then redirect to my app from my understanding.

**UPDATE:**

Correct my callback URL and problem persists.

Comment: You can try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it.

Comment: No luck there :).  But then I changed the IntentFilter decoration to   [IntentFilter(new []{Android.Content.Intent.ActionView},
        Categories = new[] {Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable},
        DataPath = "/signin-google",
        DataHost = "pay-ur-bills-355804.uc.r.appspot.com",
        DataSchemes = new[]
            {
                "https",
            })
    ] to get past the error but ran into another.

Comment: `to get past the error but ran into another` What was the another problem? Is there any log?

Comment: My urls are not correct or somehow Xamarin.Essentials is not constructing the correct URLs. I think the root of the problem is in this library as after correcting the urls, I cannot get past this subclassing error. Specifically, the call back url. I have tried is "xamarinessentials" as in https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/develop/Samples/Samples/ViewModel/WebAuthenticatorViewModel.cs but run into the same subclass error. Would help if I can see what the library is constructing.

Comment: I just looked at the Uri being composed and a slash is being appended to the end. So I send this "xamarinessentials://abc" and the Uri is composed at "xamarinessentials://abc/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific issue was being caused by a trailing slash in my redirect URL causing a mismatch between what I thought I was sending vs what the Xamarin app was constructing.

I ended up defining my redirect url as

```
someappname://callback/
```

The trailing slash ensures I can guarantee the same Uri being constructed on the Android intent which I then defined as follows:

```
[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new []{Android.Content.Intent.ActionView},
        Categories = new[] {Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable},

        // need to ensure we have a backslash 
        DataPath = "/callback/", 
        DataScheme = "someappname")
    ]

    public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {
        
    }
```

The c# Uri class will append a trailing slash at the end of your custom scheme if defined without a trailing slash and this would cause confusion as you do not expect this. The MSDN docs is not clear on this.

Comment: Wow, when did `new Uri()` start adding a trailing slash? I spent over an hour trying to figure out why my UI tests that used social logins stopped working with the 'you must subclass WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity' error. What is worse, seems no way to disable this behavior. Hopefully it doesn't affect my other intent filters from non-auth sources. Thanks for sharing.